# How to route from one server to another with Pritunl?

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, subnet

I have a Pritunl installation (free version) with two organizations and two servers.

- *CustomerOrg* is attached to *CustomerServer* that creates the subnet `10.0.1.0/24`.
- *StaffOrg* is attached to *StaffServer* that creates the subnet `10.0.2.0/24`.

I want the users in *StaffOrg* to be able to access the devices in the *CustomerServer* subnet.

I've tried adding a new route in *StaffServer* that points to `10.0.1.0/24`, but it didn't do the trick. Connections from staff to customers just timeout.

How could I achieve this behaviour?

Note: Pritunl runs within a Docker container in a Linux machine, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to run your docker with the attributes --net=hots to use the full network resources from your docker host, then try to add the required routes to your host.

Comment: That didn't help, sorry. I don't have an issue exposing ports, but routing from one subnet to another.